# smart way to calculate $z^3=\bar z $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Equation is: $z^3=\bar z$.

I tried to do open it in a regular manner, where $(a+ib)^3=a-ib$, but it seems very messy and it's hard to find a solution for it. Is there any smarter way to approach it?

I believe that I'm missing something here.

Comment: The $\TeX$ command you're looking for is `\bar z`. For longer lines, you want to use `\overline{a+bi}`: $\overline{a+bi}$.

Comment: Try polar form: $z=re^{it}$.

Answer (score 6):

By taking absolute value of both sides, we easily see that

$$|z|=1\quad\text{or}\quad|z|=0$$

Thus, if $z\ne0$, then $z=e^{i\theta}$ for some real number $\theta$, and so,

$$e^{3i\theta}=e^{-i\theta}\\3\theta=-\theta+2\pi k,\quad k\in\mathbb Z$$

Answer (score 3):

Conjugate both sides: $\bar{z}^3=z$, so you get
$$
z=\bar{z}^3=(z^3)^3=z^9
$$
Hence, $z=0$ or $z^8=1$. Are all roots of the latter also roots of the original equation?

Answer (score 1):

It's messy if you make a mess of it. Per se, if you proceed with order the cases are not that hard. Let $a,b\in\Bbb R$.

$$(a^3-3ab^2-a)+(3a^2b-b^3+b)i=0\\\begin{cases}a(a^2-3b^2-1)=0\\b(3a^2-b^2+1)=0\end{cases}\iff\\\begin{cases}a=0\\ b=0\end{cases}\vee \begin{cases}a=0\\ b=\pm1\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a=\pm1\\b=0\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a^2-3b^2=1\\ b^2-3a^2=1\end{cases}\iff\\\begin{cases}a=0\\ b=0\end{cases}\vee \begin{cases}a=0\\ b=\pm1\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a=\pm1\\b=0\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}4(a^2-b^2)=0\\ b^2=1+3a^2\end{cases}\iff\\\begin{cases}a=0\\ b=0\end{cases}\vee \begin{cases}a=0\\ b=\pm1\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a=\pm1\\b=0\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a^2=b^2\\ -2b^2=1\end{cases}\iff\\\begin{cases}a=0\\ b=0\end{cases}\vee \begin{cases}a=0\\ b=\pm1\end{cases}\vee\begin{cases}a=\pm1\\b=0\end{cases}$$